# PlasticSCM CLI - how to list all folders in repo?

Tags: command-line-interface, plasticscm

I'm using the below command to list the contents of a repo, but would like to limit the results to only include folders (i.e. no files).

```
cm ls --tree=br:branch@repo@server:port -R --format={path}
```

Using **cm help ls** does not seem to indicate how or whether this is possible.

Edit: I realise I could filter client side, but I do not want to do this as some of our repos are large (contain many files) and this is too slow.

Edit: Using the path filtering **ls** provides seems like it would work... but, I can't find a way to get it to only include folders. For example, `cm ls *.cs` would include all .cs files.

Edit: Looking like my only option will be to recursively walk a repo's "file system", pulling it one folder at a time and recursing into each subfolder - this will hopefully be much faster than pulling everything using the recursive **ls** option and then filtering it all client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily my use-case was for populating a user interface. So, I could get away with not using the **-r** (recursive) option and instead simply query the path content of each folder as the user navigated. As Carlos suggested, this involves querying the path content and then discarding the non-folder data (all done client side). While more tedious to implement, it works and is performant enough.

It would be good if **ls** (or some other mechanism) allowed you to retrieve only folder data and the filtering all done server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "cm ls --format="{path}||{type}" and then you can grep the output based on the item type.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned unfortunately client side processing isn't an option - it takes too long to pull all the data (folder & file info) to the client machine.